# Hiding data from Libraries/sdks on Android

Tags: android, security

I have a question on security on Android.
I am planning to use some sdks/libraries inside my android app.
I want to make sure tose sdks/library do not access my user's data.
One way to do that would be to save user's data in enrypted format.
I want to know what are the best practices to achieve this.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Manan

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to protect? (Size,Type(Strings,DB's etc),And Use (financial, passwords or ... ?) Secondly why would you use a 3rd party lib that would potentially steal it, just curious as to why you think that "Might" happen ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you include libraries within your app, then they will run under the same UID as the rest of your app, so there is really no way to protect against them doing so. Even if your app encrypts the data, it would need access to the keys that could be used to decrypt it, so the libraries, since they are running as part of yoru app, would have access to those keys as well. (Note that this implies a very sophisticated library specified designed to access the data in your application, which is **highly** unlikely.)

If you are really concerned about this, then you could include the library code in a separate application and have your application make calls to it. For example, you could deploy the library collection as a background service and require a custom permission in order to bind to it that only your application would request/have. You could then use custom permissions to lock down access to functions/APIs within your own application that would provide the data the library needs so that only your separate library would be able to get to that data.

**It's worth pointing out (again), that if you are planning to use standard/general-purpose libraries, the odds of them including code to specifically understand the data structures your app is using and obtaining illicit access to that data is very unlikely. Perhaps I'm not really understanding your threat model here.**

Comment: Thanks jeffsix for such a nice explanation.... The problem is I am getiing libraries from some developers and I want to absolutely make sure that our data is secure although I am sure its highly unlikely. But I cannot take any risks as the data my application has can be misused very badly....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that nobody will access your private data it is better to encrypt it, in one of my project I use http://sqlcipher.net/ and would recommend it to you.

It is a wrapper framework around sqlite3 which allows to encrypt database file, in this case it would be more reliable from security point of view